# Is there a way to create a VPC destination to a VPC in another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-iot

So I have a VPC Peering connection created between VPCA that is in eu-west-1 and VPCB that is in us-east-1. I have updated the route tables and all. I am trying to create a Rule that would allow me to send all the messages from the topic "helloWorld/#" within IoT Core to an MSK in another region.

The rule actions ask me for a VPC Destination, when creating a new VPC Destination I can only select the VPCs in the region I'm in - which does make sense... is there a way to select the VPC Peering connection or alternatively the VPC in the other region?

[image: Create a destination]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Destination creator doesn't accept a VPC Peering or an alternative it is simpler to move the infrastructure or use the IoT in the same region. Alternatively the use of a Lambda or similar is possible, but there would be the issue of rising costs. Therefore, the former option of using the same region was applied in my case.